# How to Output the Results from Postman Runner

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am calling the same API around 3000 times using Postman. I've setup a Runner where I read an ID from a CSV. I want to be able to output which responses give me a 404 back. However, I don't seem to see a way to do this in Postman

Looks like I can "View Results" and "Export Results" but that only shows if an exception has occurred I think.

Is there any way I can get an exportable list from Postman of all my 404s? Or even better, have Postman write the status codes back to my CSV that it's reading from?

Comment: looking more online and looks like I may be able to use some opensource tool called Newman